# How do I detect non-letters with virtual codes in the Windows API?

Tags: c++, winapi

In the Windows API and Direct2D/DirectWrite, I'm detecting the virtual code so text input in a 2D GUI can be appended. While it works fine, How can I include non-letters, such as !?., etc.

For example, when I press Shift+1, I get '1' instead of '!'. When I press '.', I get a boxed character. Can this detection be checked in this function somehow?

```
 wchar_t TextBox::charIsPressed(int getKey)
 {
char letter = getKey; 

// Check for space character
if (letter == ' ')
    return (wchar_t)letter; 

// Check if the input is no letter
if ((getKey >= 'A') && (getKey <= 'Z'))
{
    if (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
        letter += 0x20;
}

return (wchar_t)letter;
 }
```

It's calling function:

```
// Keyboard support 
static X2D::Win32::KeyEvent *keyEvent; 

if (m_focused)
{
    // Check if there's editing space
    if ((m_x + m_text.getWidth()) > (m_x + getWidth()))
        return;

    // Get the latest key event
    keyEvent = frm.getKeyEvent();

    if (!keyEvent->processed) 
    { 
        // Was backspace pressed?
        if (keyEvent->virtual_code == VK_BACK)
        {
            m_text.setText(m_text.getText().substr(0, m_text.getText().length() - 1));  
        }
        else if (keyEvent->virtual_code == VK_RETURN)
        {
            m_focused = false;
        }
        else
        {
            m_text.setText(m_text.getText() + charIsPressed(keyEvent->virtual_code));
        }

        keyEvent->processed = true;
    }  
}
```

Edit:
I found a way for detecting single characters, so it's a start.

```
    // Converts '1' to '!'
if (getKey == '1')
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
        return '!';
}
```

Though typing '.' is getting me a semi-snowman Ascii figure.

Comment: Why don't you let the system do the heavy lifting for you? Simply handle `WM_CHAR` and everything just works. No need to manually compose input to wind up with what the system already does for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (this is Delphi, but it allows you to see the principle of translation):

```
function VKToChar(AVirtualCode: Word; out AChar: WideChar): Boolean;
var
  KeyboardState: TKeyboardState;
  ScanCode: DWORD;
  Temp: UnicodeString;
  Char: WideChar;
begin
  AChar := #0;
  Result := GetKeyboardState(KeyboardState);
  if not Result then Exit;
  ScanCode := MapVirtualKey(AVirtualCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
  SetLength(Temp, 3);
  if ToUnicode(AVirtualCode, ScanCode, KeyboardState, PWideChar(Temp), Length(Temp), 0) = 1 then
    begin
      AChar := Temp[1];
      Result := True;
    end
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: GetKeyboardState is surely not compatible with GetAsyncKeyState. *An application can call this function to retrieve the current status of all the virtual keys. The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue, nor does it change as keyboard messages are posted to or retrieved from message queues of other threads.*